# Python Translation from excel file

Tags: python, xlrd, goslate

I would like to translate the words which are stored in the excel file in column A

I have 2 parts (part 1 and Part 2 as stated below) of code, I do not know how to merge these both codes for successful translation for each word in to column B.

Looking for your help

**Reading Excel file: code of part 1**

```
import xlrd


 # Give the location of the file 
loc = (r"path\fruits.xlsx") 
  
# To open Workbook 
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 
sheet.cell_value(0, 0) 
  
for i in range(sheet.nrows): 
    print(sheet.cell_value(i, 0))
```

**Translation : Code of Part 2**

```
import goslate

text = "i am coming tomorrow"

gs = goslate.Goslate()
translatedText = gs.translate(text, 'de')

print(translatedText)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import xlrd
import goslate

loc = r"C:\Users\kumarant\Desktop\Django\sahil\fruits.xlsx"
gs = goslate.Goslate()

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
  
for i in range(sheet.nrows): 
    print(gs.translate(sheet.cell_value(i, 0), 'de'))
```

Comment: how to write the result in column B in the excel sheet